# SQL Select with Len - Conversion Failed?

Tags: sql, type-conversion, patindex

This is my query:

```
SELECT at.AssetTag, 
dp.Custodian,
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%_%', dp.Custodian) = '0'
THEN dp.Custodian 
ELSE RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(dp.Custodian)),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(dp.Custodian)) - PATINDEX('%_%', dp.Custodian))) END AS FirstName, 
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%_%', dp.Custodian) = '0' 
THEN '' 
ELSE LEFT(dp.Custodian, PATINDEX('%_%', dp.Custodian)-1) END AS LastName, RIGHT(at.Assettag,3) AS MediaTypeSuffix
FROM tblAssetTracking at (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN tblDiscoveryProcessing dp (NOLOCK) ON dp.FKAsset = at.ID 
WHERE dp.Custodian Is Not Null
```

When I run it I get an error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XXX' to data type int" (xxx is an actual value I had to replace).  Can anyone help, please?  Ps. I hope the statement went into the code block right.  Apparently, I don't understand how to paste code in properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I had to remove the trimming:

```
SELECT at.AssetTag, 
dp.Custodian, 
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[_]%', dp.Custodian) = '0'
    THEN dp.Custodian 
    ELSE RIGHT(dp.Custodian,LEN(dp.Custodian) - PATINDEX('%[_]%', dp.Custodian))
END AS FirstName, 
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[_]%', dp.Custodian) = '0' 
    THEN '' 
    ELSE LEFT(dp.Custodian, PATINDEX('%[_]%', dp.Custodian)-1) 
END AS LastName, 
RIGHT(at.Assettag,3) AS MediaTypeSuffix
FROM tblAssetTracking at (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblDiscoveryProcessing dp (NOLOCK) ON dp.FKAsset = at.ID
WHERE dp.Custodian Is Not Null
```